# Vue.js data objects don't work with some lodash functions?

Tags: javascript, lodash, vue.js

I'm doing a little **store pattern** as indicated in the [docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State-Management).

Here is my store object:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import _ from 'lodash';

class EmployeeService {

  constructor() {
    this.employees = null;
    this.url = 'http://url';
  }

  all() {
    if (this.employees === null) {
      return Vue.http.get(this.url)
        .then(response => (this.employees = response.data.data));
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.employees));
  }

  find(id) {
    const employee = _.find(this.employees, { id });

     if (_.isUndefined(employee)) {
       return Vue.http.get(`${this.url}/${id}`)
         .then(response => response.data);
     }

    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(employee));
  }

}

export default new EmployeeService();
```

The problem is in the `find(id)` method, whenever I use the lodash function `_.find()`, it **always** returns `undefined`, even when the object does exist. But when I use vanilla js, like this:

```
const employee = this.employees.flter(emp => emp.id == id)[0];
```

It has no problem finding the object.

I would like to know why this happens, and find if it's a bug or is an expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem of Vue.js. But it's in your `_.find`. As the [lodash docs _find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) says:

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning the first element predicate returns truthy for.

In your code `_.find(this.employees, { id });`, `{ id }` doesn't return a truthy value. For the predicate parameter, you should use

```
function(o) {
    return o.id == id;
}
```

Or shorthand: `{'id': id}`.

Comment: But I AM doing just that, using the es6 feature [object short-hand](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand), `{ id: id } == { id }`. But either way, I tried as you said before posting and didn't work either

Comment: when saying shorthand, I mean: `const employee = _.find(this.employees, { 'id': id });`

Comment: I indeed tried as you said, but it is not working. If `this.employees` was a mere array it would work. But Vue.js does something to it so every component can update when the data inside `this.employees` changes.

Comment: See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFe6RI16vxe6SfnvuFUk?p=preview), in script.js, there is a method `findId1`. In this method, `_find` works well. Besides, in your example, `EmployeeService` is just a normal ES6 class, nothing special with Vue.js. For your problem, I suggest you to create a plunker so that the others can help you.

Comment: It turns out that Lodash was internally using the `===` operator, I manually passed the predicate parameter using `==` and everything worked.

Comment: It's the reason that I use `==` but not `===` in `function(o) {
    return o.id == id;
}`.